# error "Local workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found." al intentar ejecutar aplicacion en angular 2 con bootstrap

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

> Estoy siguientos los pasos de este [tutorial](http://www.gistia.com/getting-started-angular-2-bootstrap/) para implementar
>   Angular 2 con bootstrap 4 en el.

**yo nunca antes habia usado bootstrap 4 con angular 2 yo usaba puro CSS3 desde el archivo css.**

cuando intente ejecutar con el comando `ng serve` pero al ejecutar la terminal me da el siguiente error:

```
Local workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found.
Error: Local workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found.
    at WorkspaceLoader._getProjectWorkspaceFilePath (/usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/workspace-loader.js:37:19)
    at WorkspaceLoader.loadWorkspace (/usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/workspace-loader.js:24:21)
    at ServeCommand._loadWorkspaceAndArchitect (/usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/architect-command.js:180:32)
    at ServeCommand. (/usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/architect-command.js:47:25)
    at Generator.next ()
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/architect-command.js:7:71
    at new Promise ()
    at __awaiter (/usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/architect-command.js:3:12)
    at ServeCommand.initialize (/usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/architect-command.js:46:16)
    at Object. (/usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/command-runner.js:87:23)
```

ha primera vista veo que no encuentra el archivo `angular.json`  mi pregunta es:

donde deberia crear ese archivo en la carpeta root del proyecto?

el tutorial me comenta que debo agregar esto en ese archivo:

```
{
// ...other config
"styles": [
  "styles.css",
  "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  ]
}
```

**NOTA:El unico archivo con extension JSON es este : package.json**

aqui esta todo mis archivos del proyecto:

```
Angular2/angular-bootstrap# ls
e2e  karma.conf.js  package.json  protractor.conf.js  README.md  src  tsconfig.json  tslint.json
root@me:/home/memee/Desktop/test/Angular2/angular-bootstrap#
```

intente agregar bootstrap desde el `index.html` en la carpeta `src` de la aplicacion pero no me funciono.

```html
  GNU nano 2.5.3                      File: index.html                                                   

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularBootstrap</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" i$

</head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  </div>

  <div>
    We are using nothing more than Bootstrap CSS.

    This works for styles. If we want to use JavaScript powered components, we'll have to do some manual$

    <button class="btn btn-primary">Click me!</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

alguna idea? en los pasos para agregar bootstrap 4?

Answer (score 1):

1. Asegurate de estar haciendo el `checkout` completo.

   Deben estar todos los archivos del [repositorio de GitHub](https://github.com/Cartab/angular-bootstrap). Recuerda que antes de la version 6 de Angular se usaba el archivo de configuraciones `.angular-cli.json` que puede que esté escondido.
2. Actualizar el proyecto.

   Si todos los archivos están allí. Ahora tenés que actualizar el proyecto. El tutorial usa una versián anterior de Angular 6. Ahora se usa el archivo 'angular.json', que es el que te falta.

   Para actualizar sigue los pasos en [la guia de actualización](https://update.angular.io/). Los que más te interesan son los comandos:

   ```
   npm install @angular/cli
   ng update @angular/cli
   ```

   Con esto, se pasa el archivo `.angular-cli.json` al nuevo formato de `angular.json`

Comment: en archivo angular-clin.json esta en la misma carpeta de root?

Comment: en archivo angular-clin.json esta en la misma carpeta de root?

Comment: debeja mirar si lo estoy haciendo bien quiza me salte un paso,ahi comento cuando lo vea.

Comment: el archivo `.angular-cli.json` debe estar en la misma carpeta que el `package.json`

Comment: Ten en cuenta que es `.angular-cli.json` no `angular-clin.json`... Con `.` al inicio y sin `n`

Comment: deja mirar los archivos ocultos del proyectos

Comment: Si esta o cualquier otra respuesta ha resuelto tu problema, por favor considera [aceptarla](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) clicando la marca de check (en forma de V debajo de la puntuación de la respuesta). Esto indica a la comunidad que has encontrado una solución y de paso os dará reputación a ambos (a tí y quien ha respondido). Por supuesto, no tienes ninguna obligación de hacerlo.